# UITableView not scrolling down and bouncing back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 views: one is `main view` inside which I am generating a popover in which table view will be shown. I'm using a `table view` inside a `popoverController`.My popover size is (700,264). I have a different xib for mt table view i.e `PopovertableView Controller`. I am setting my table size to (0,0.700,352) and giving row height as 44. My userlistTable has 8 objects in it. I am not getting what is going wrong, I have already tried setting my table height more than 352

here is my code

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
 NSLog(@"row in table");
 NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection returning %d", [userlistTable count]);
 return [ userlistTable count];
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

 if(textField == universityTextField)
    {
     if(popOverController == nil)
            {
                PopoverTableViewController *popovertableViewController=     [[PopoverTableViewController alloc]init];

                self.popOverController  = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popovertableViewController];

             }

       popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(700,264);
       [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(40, 268, 410, 46) inView:textField.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    }

return NO;
}
```

Comment: Try to uncheck the UseAutolayout in the xib

Comment: @Tendulkar thank you so much.. but it didn't work. what i have done is i have fixed my table size to (700,264) and fixed the row size to 44(as i have 8 objects in my table view). Now its working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What really was happening since your row height was 44 and you had 8 objects in it so at height 44*8 (.i.e 352) or more than that , your tableview would not scroll. Your total height of the table view should be less than (**numberoOfRows)*(rowHeight)** if you want the tableview to scroll.And this is the reason that after you made it 264 it worked fine. **The scrolling is related to the height of the tableView not the area of tableview that is visible**. Hope this clarifies if you had any doubt.